# Can I limit native-style scrolling to one axis in Mobile Safari?

Tags: html, css, ios, webkit, mobile-safari

To enable native style scrolling on DOM elements in Mobile Safari, you can use this custom CSS property on the containing element:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Is it possible to limit the scrolling to only a single axis? My goal is to achieve the equivalent of this:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Defining the standard CSS properties as above does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can find, it appears that this is not currently possible. So as not to leave anyone hanging, I'll mark this as the correct answer until/if Apple ever makes a relevant change in Mobile Safari's behavior.